# C# lambda expression "type" confusion

Tags: c#, types, pattern-matching, overloading

In a class i am working on i have three methods with the same name but different parameters (overload). One of this three method is an override of a base class.

Here the three method signature :

```
public override IQueryable<tbl_usr_User> Read(Expression<Func<tbl_usr_User, bool>> searchCriteria = null)
public IQueryable<tbl_usr_Company> Read(Expression<Func<tbl_usr_Company, bool>> searchCriteria = null)
public IQueryable<tbl_usr_Contact> Read(Expression<Func<tbl_usr_Contact, bool>> searchCriteria = null)
```

Now when i would like to use the Read method that will read user i do that :

```
this.Read<tbl_usr_User>(usr => usr.NAME == "John");
```

Because i have explicitly state the return type, i expect the method can match the right overload, but i found out that is not the case, and compiler mistakeny think i would call the Company read method.
The only way i found to convince the compiler about my intention is to rewrite the instruction as follow :

```
        Expression<Func<tbl_usr_User, bool>> expression = user => user.NAME == "John";
        result = this.Read(expression);
```

What am i missing here? Why compiler does not take the overload with the right return type? There isn't a concise way to instruct about the lambda type without having to create a dedicated variable?

Answer (score 4):

Those methods aren't generic, they just return a generic type, so you can't call them as if they are. You could specify the type of the Lambda though, for example:

```
result = Read((tbl_usr_User usr) => usr.NAME == "John");
```

Comment: wow beautiful way to type a lamda, i didn't know it was possibile to do. Thanks a lot for have pointed out. Also the fact that my method aren't generic clarify what is happening